# Looping over group in a Python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

EDIT: I've gotten it work--I had forgotten to put in a space as a separator for multiple edges.

I've got this Python regex, which handles most of the strings I have to parse.

`edge_value_pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<edge>e[0-9]+) +(?P<label1>[^ ]*)[^"]+"(?P<word>[^"]+)"[^:]+:: (?P<label2>[^\n]+)')`

Here is an example string that my regex is meant to parse:

`'e0    BIKE-EVENT              1 "biking" 2'`

It correctly stores `e0` into the `edge` group, `BIKE-EVENT` into the `label1` group, and `"biking"` into the `word` group.  The last group, `label2`, is for a slightly different variation of the string, as shown below.  Note that the `label2` regex group behaves as expected when given a string like the one below.

`'e29 e30                          "of" :: of, OF'`

However, the regex pattern fills in `label1` with the value `e30.`  The truth is that this string does not have any `label1` value--it should be `None` or at least the empty string.  An ad-hoc solution would be to parse `label1` with a regex to determine if it's an actual label or just another edge.  I want to know if there is way to modify my original regex so that the group `edge` takes in all `edges`.  E.g., the output for the above string would be:

`edge = "e29 e30"`

`label1 = None`

`word = of`

`label2 = of, OF`

I tried this solution below, which I thought would translate to simply looping over the first group, `edge` (this would be trivial if I had an actual FSA), but it doesn't change the behavior of the regex.

`edge_value_pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<edge>(e[0-9]+)+) +(?P<label1>[^ ]*)[^"]+"(?P<word>[^"]+)"[^:]+:: (?P<label2>[^\n]+)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `edge` to match `"e29 e30"`, you have to put the repetition *inside* the group, not outside.

You did that by sticking a new group inside the `edge` group with a `+` repetition—which is fine, although you probably wanted a non-capturing group there—but you forgot to include the space inside the repeating group.

(You also left the external repeat, and used a capturing group where you probably wanted a non-capturing, but those are less serious.)

Look at just that fragment:

```
(?P<edge>(e[0-9]+)+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/cCXtUczdmysrDBts)

Here, the expression catches `e29` as one match, then `e30` as a subsequent match. So, if you add anything else to the expression, it's either going to miss `e29`, or just fail. But add the space:

```
(?P<edge>(e[0-9]+ )+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0ipmrnTCfSUqN6Iw)

And now it's matching `e29 e30` plus the trailing space as a single match, which means you can tack on any additional stuff and it will work (as long as you get that additional stuff right—you still need to remove the extra `+`, and I think you may need to make a couple of other repetitions non-greedy…).